# check if the user redircted from login page using php

Tags: php

I have a social media website for univesrsity. I will give a specific users a temprory username and password at first time he login into website. after he inserted data..will be redirected to a registration page to insert a full and real data.

my question is How do I know that is authenticated user and it has been redirected from login page to bring up some data related to him and put it in the form, otherwise, show registration form empty without any data for a new user.
I used this code to check if the user has been redirected ?

```
 $preURL = "http://localhost/social/login.php"; 
 if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $preURL
        && $_SESSION['empInfo'] != "") {
        showRegistrationForm($errors,$_SESSION['empInfo']);
}
else {
    showRegistrationForm($errors,$empInfo);
}
```

`$_SESSION['empInfo']`
containes data I want to put it into registration form.
is `setcookie()` should be enough ?

Comment: Why dont use session data?

Comment: are you calling session_start() at some point before referencing the session variables?  And what Simon says, if you are using sessions then just use sessions, not sessions and browser side cookies...

Comment: @SimonMüller yes, But I said maybe session remains active and the user is not allowed access to the form. So, I choose to use cookies with session !!
There is no need to use cookies?

Comment: @ivanivan yes, I used session_start()

Comment: when you want to register persistent users you should use a database. You can do it with sessions but then its related to theyre computer and browser. its also not secure